# File size 0 bytes when uploaded curl ftp

Tags: bash, curl, ftp, backup

Help my please. I have got one bug in my backup script. File size 0 bytes when uploaded curl ftp. And cut file name: "siteru=2013-09-27(17". Why?

When the script is executed, there are no errors. Uploading to ftp is completely up to 100%

```
#!/bin/bash
#
#ver 1.0
#2013-09-09
#
DBHOST="mysql-host" 
DBUSER="mysql-user"  
DBPASS="mysql-pass"  
DBNAME="mysql-db" 
DBARC=$DBNAME.sql.gz  
#
WEBDAVURL="ftp-url"
WEBDAVUSER="ftp-usr"
WEBDAVPASS="ftp-pass"
#
SCRIPTDIR="/home/site/site.com/docs/backup/"
SCRDIR="/home/site/site.com/docs/"
SCREXCLUDE="backup"
SCRARC="site-com.tar.gz"
#
ARCNAME="sitecom"=$(date '+%F(%H:%M)')".tar"
MAXARC="20"
#    
cd $SCRDIR
#   
tar cfz $SCRIPTDIR$SCRARC --exclude=$SCREXCLUDE *
# 
cd $SCRIPTDIR
#  
mysqldump -h$DBHOST -u$DBUSER -p$DBPASS $DBNAME | gzip > $DBARC
#
tar cf $SCRIPTDIR$ARCNAME $SCRARC $DBARC
#
curl --upload-file $ARCNAME ftp://$WEBDAVUSER:$WEBDAVPASS@$WEBDAVURL
#
rm *.gz
#
ls -t *.tar | tail -n+$MAXARC | xargs rm -f
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your filename contains characters (`(`, `)`) that would typically need to be escaped.

You need to quote the variable.  Say:

```
curl --upload-file "$ARCNAME" ftp://$WEBDAVUSER:$WEBDAVPASS@$WEBDAVURL
```